# Is there a way to detect when a power point presentation has entered full screen via python?

Tags: python, windows, powerpoint

I'm attempting to figure out a. If Microsoft Power Point is running, and b. If so, is it running in full screen mode or "slide show" mode.

Detecting whether or not an instance of PowerPoint is running was fairly straight forward.

```
def check_for_ppt():
    global ppt 
    stime = time.time()
    f = (os.popen('tasklist').read())
    if 'POWERPNT.EXE' in f:
        ppt = True
    else: 
        ppt = False
```

But I'm unsure where to go from here. Is there a way to detect the state of another program? I guess in a pinch, I could ping parts of the extremes of the screen and test whether the pixels returned black or not (as they would be during a presentation), and just hope that I don't get too many false positives. But outside of that, I'm not sure.

Can python 'hook' into another program and see what's going on?

Comment: Your question is incredibly vague.  Do you mean given a *.ppt file, determine if it has ever been made full screen?

Comment: I think he's referring to a running presentation

Comment: @Yatrix -- Correct. I've clarified my point a bit now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably do this using [PowerPoint's COM interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb265987%28v=office.12%29) and the [win32com.client module](http://oreilly.com/catalog/pythonwin32/chapter/ch12.html).

I don't have PPT here to write the code, but it looks like you'll have to connect to PPT and get the Application.Presentations object and find the active Presentation.  When you have the active [Presentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb251586%28v=office.12%29), get its [SlideShowSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb230631%28v=office.12%29.aspx) and check its [ShowType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb230620%28v=office.12%29.aspx) for ppShowTypeKiosk.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to utilize the PowerPoint interop which will give you access to a variety of "stuff" that the PPT presentation is doing or what state it's in. This won't be a simple task as you'll have to get that working somehow with your Python app.

I'm not familiar with Python, personally, so I have no idea what you'll have to do for that. Maybe a .NET wrapper around the Interop that will expose what's needed to the Python app, if you can't do so directly. I have experience with .NET and the interops and it's not simple using all MS technologies, either.

This is a pretty generic answer, I realize. I just don't think that it's a simple thing to accomplish, regardless of language or IDE.